# TypeScript: Deep traversal of plain and immutablejs objects

Tags: typescript, immutable.js

I have a function that traverses deep into objects: `$get(['deep', 'inside'], object)`.
I was able to type it like this:

```
...
export function $get<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2], T>(path: [K1, K2, K3], subject: T): T[K1][K2][K3];
export function $get<K1 extends keyof T, K2 extends keyof T[K1], T>(path: [K1, K2], subject: T): T[K1][K2];
export function $get<K1 extends keyof T, T>(path: [K1], subject: T): T[K1];
```

Now I need to make it work with immutableJS Map objects.
Basically I need to be able to do smth like this:

```
function $get<K1 extends keyof T, T>(path: [K1], subject: T): T.get(K1);
```

But obviously it's not possible. Any ideas how to make it work?
A possible workaround is just to use something like `seamless-immutable`, but I just want to know all of my options.

Comment: Do you mean working with immutable `Records` ? Because a `Map` has just the type for the key (ie `string` for example) and not any way of assigning specific keys to different value types like a record

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes we use `Map`s, and it is possible to type them. E.g. smth like this would work: https://blog.mayflower.de/6630-typescript-redux-immutablejs.html